# Long Polling in Angular2 js/socket.io

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io, rxjs, observable

We have a requirement where we need to establish a connection with server, where that port of the server is kept opened until the response is completely received.This has to be achieved by making only single service call.Can someone help in solving this issue using angular2 or socket io. Is there any way of achieving this using observables.

Here is the code we kept..

```
        let socket = io(service  url);
        socket.on('connect', function(){
        socket.emit('authentication', {username: "username", password: "password"});
        socket.emit()
        socket.on('authenticated', function() {
                alert('authenticated!!')
            });
        });
```

Comment: Is there an error here ... ?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYMAI-j 404 (Not Found) .This is the error.